# grids/contect pushed off to the right in small devices/phones webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a portfolio for myself, trying to have the website fit well on phones. currently, the sections are pushed to the right when you go phone mode. This problem only occurs when I go to dev view and select a real phone, but when I resize the window normally they are not pushed to the right.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Here is my setup so far. PhoneModeProblem picture.

INDEX.css - the whole webpage structure

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');

/*
    every element will have the folowing
*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;

}
/*
    Our CSS variables are here
    Colors of our page
*/
:root{
    --color-bg: #0c243c;
    --color-bg-variant: #c9d1d5;
    --color-primary: #55c2c3;
    --color-primary-variant: #7e8c9c;
    --color-white: #fff;
    --color-light: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);

    --transition: all 400ms ease;

    --container-width-lg: 75%;
    --container-width-md: 86%;
    --container-width-sm: 90%;

}

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    
}
/**
    remove scroll bar
*/
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: var(--color-bg);
    color: var(--color-white);
    line-height: 1.7;
    background-image: url(../src/assests/image-from-rawpixel-id-3944564-original.png);

}

/* ============ GENERAL SYTLES ===========*/

.container{
    width: var(--container-width-lg);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{
    font-weight: 500;
    

}
h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;

}

section{
    margin-top: 8rem;
   

}
section > h2, section > h5{
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--color-light); 
}

section > h2 { 
    color: var(--color-primary);
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.text-light{
    color: var(--color-light);
    
}

a{
    color: var(--color-primary);
    transition: var(--transition);
}

a:hover{
    color: var(--color-white);
}

/* buttons */
.btn{
    width: max-content;
    display: inline-block;
    color: var(--color-primary);
    padding: 0.75rem 1.2rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-primary);
    transition: var(--transition);  
}

.btn:hover{
    background: var(--color-white);
    color: var(--color-bg);
    border-color: transparent;

}

.btn-primary{
    background: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-bg);
}

img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* =================  (MEDIUM DEVICES/TABLETS) MEDIA QUERIES ================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container{
        width: var(--container-width-md);
    }

    section{
        margin: 6rem;   
    }
}

/* ================= (SMALL DEVICES/PHONES) MEDIA QUERIES ================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container{
        width: var(--container-width-sm);
    }

    section > h2{
        margin-bottom: 2rem;   
    }
}
```

Experience.css - the problem rises after styling

```
.experience__container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 2rem;
}

.experience__container > div {
    background: var(--color-bg);
    padding: 2.4rem 5rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: var(--transition);
}
.experience__container > div:hover{
    background: transparent;
    border-color: var(--color-primary-variant);
    
}
.experience__container > div h3{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    color: var(--color-primary);
}
.experience__contect{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 1.7rem;
}

.experience__details{
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.experience__details-icon{
    margin-top: 6px;
    color: var(--color-primary);
}
.experience__frontend{
    align-items: center;
}

/* =================  (MEDIUM DEVICES/tablets) MEDIA QUERIES ================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .experience__container{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .experience__container > div{
        width: 80%;
        padding: 2rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .experience__contect{
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    
 
 }
 
 /* ================= (SMALL DEVICES/PHONES) MEDIA QUERIES ================ */
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .experience__container{
         gap: 1rem;
     }
     .experience__container > div{
         width: 100%;
         padding: 2rem;
     }
     .experience__contect{
         padding: 1rem;
     }

 }
```

experience.jsx - Where the problem happnes in small devices.

```
import React from 'react'
import './experience.css'
import {BsPatchCheckFill} from 'react-icons/bs'

const experience = () => {
  return (
    <section id='experience'>
      <h5>What Skills I Have</h5>
      <h2>My Experience</h2>
      <div className="container experience__container">
        <div className="experience__frontend">
          <h3> Frontend Development</h3>
          <div className="experience__contect">
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon' />
              <div>
                <h4>HTML</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Intermediate</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>CSS</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Intermediate</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>JavaScript</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Basic</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>React</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Intermediate</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>BootStrap</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Basic</small>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* END OF FRONT END */}
        <div className="experience__backend">
          <h3>Backend Development</h3>
          <div className="experience__contect">
        <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Java</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Intermediate</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>Python</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Intermediate</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>C#</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Intermediate</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>Node JS</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Basic</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='experience__details'>
              <BsPatchCheckFill className='experience__details-icon'/>
              <div>
                <h4>Microsoft SQL</h4>
                <small className='text-light'>Basic</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default experience
```

Comment: Have you got something like this in your head element <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, when inspecting the page the head element says the exact thing you mentioned. When I change the initial scale it does zoom out and the section are not moved to the right anymore